# sql with set difference capability

Tags: sql, db2

suppose I've these two tables with the sample data:

[image: Employee Table]

[image: Employee_Roles Table]

I want to find which employees don't have the role say 5330. The answer should be employee 2 & 3.

If I simply try doing a employee left outer join with employee_roles with where role_id <> 5330 it includes employee 1 as well but that should not be the case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using DB2? because you put a "db2" tag but it seems a generic database question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `Where Not Exists`:

```
Select  e.*
From    employee    e
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    employee_roles  r
    Where   r.employee_id = e.employee_id
    And     r.role_id = 5330
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax for the `left outer join` version:

```
select e.*
from employee e left outer join
     employee_roles er
     on er.employee_id = e.employee_id and er.role_id = 5330
where er.employee_id is null;
```

The logic is that you use the `left outer join` to look for matches and returns the rows where there is no match.  It is very important the the condition on `role_id` be in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause.

You can also phrase this query using `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 supports the EXCEPT operator, right? So this would give you the employee_id for every employee who doesn't have the role 5330.

```
select employee_id 
from employee_roles
except 
select employee_id
from employee_roles
where role_id = 5330;
```

You can join that result set to the "employee" table to get their names, if you need their names.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

```
Select e.employee_name
From employee
Where employee_id Not In
    (Select distinct employee_id 
     From employee_roles 
     where role_id = 5330)
```

or

```
Select e.employee_name
From employee e
Where Not exists
    (Select * From employee_roles 
     where employee_id = e.employee_id
         and role_id = 5330)
```